# Resetting after using Dir and GetAttr

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I currently have a VBA function that puts the names of all subfolders in a given directory into a ListBox. Intending to further modulize this process, I am splitting this into a function that reads subfolder names into an array, and then another function which populates a ListBox with the array contents.

The segment of code that I have for obtaining subfolder names looks like this:

```
Sub FoldernamesToListbox(lookin As String)
    directory = Dir$(lookin & "*.*", vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(directory)
        If directory <> "." And directory <> ".." And GetAttr(lookin & directory) And vbDirectory Then
            MyBox.AddItem directory
        End If
        directory = Dir$()
    Loop
End Sub
```

In order to create a function that reads this into an array I have created an additional function that counts the number of subfolders, very similar to the one above, in order to provide a size to the array, thus avoiding slow "ReDim Preserve" calls.

```
Function CountFolders(lookinPath As String) As Integer
    j = 0
    directory = Dir$(lookinPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(directory)
        If directory <> "." And directory <> ".." And GetAttr(lookinPath & directory) And vbDirectory Then
            j = j + 1
        End If
        directory = Dir$()
    Loop
    CountFolders = j
End Function
```

However, when I use the counting function within the new function that adds folder names to an array, there seems to be errors with the Dir$() command in the function:

```
Sub FoldernamesToArray(lookin As String)
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    ReDim MyArray(CountFolders(lookin))
    directory = Dir$(lookin & "*.*", vbDirectory)
    j = 0
    Do While Len(directory)
        If directory <> "." And directory <> ".." And GetAttr(lookin & directory) And vbDirectory Then
            j = j + 1
            MyArray(j) = directory
        End If
        directory = Dir$()          'ERROR OCCURS HERE
    Loop
End Sub
```

This seems to be occuring because of the presence of a function call to CountFolders. If I hardcode the number in the function it seems to run fine. What is it about the properties of the Dir$() function or GetAttr that are causing this issue?

Comment: You can only use one "instance" of `Dir()` at any given time, so it's not possible to "nest" two separate Dir() loops. One solution is to (eg) store all results from the first Dir before making any calls to a second one.

Comment: I had assumed that when the CountFolders function finishes, then that instance should be destroyed, is that not true? I'm confused why they are interfering because in my code I call CountFolders which finishes before I use Dir$ later on in this code.

Comment: I retract my previous comment ;-)   If you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module you will see that your `CountFolders` parameter is called `PathName` but inside the function you use `lookinPath`

Comment: Oh thanks, you're right! I actually just pasted a simllified version here and obviously didnt make it fully consistent so that isnt an issue in my code.

Comment: So maybe try editing your question to show your exact code.  Not much point in testing something which is different from the actual problem.

Comment: It's essentially the same, just with all the checks eliminated from the beginning with select case statements and such. The inherent syntax remains though.

Comment: Are you adding a terminating "\" when you call your function?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: note there is a difference between adding or not adding a terminating `\` when you call your CountFolders.  I added a line to take care of that.

I'm not sure you're gaining anything by this appraoch of separately counting fsub-folders though: using `Redim Preserve` is likely *less* overhead than looping twice over the folder structure.

```
Function CountFolders(lookinPath As String) As Integer
    j = 0
    directory = Dir$(lookinPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(directory)
        If directory <> "." And directory <> ".." Then
            If GetAttr(lookinPath & directory) And vbDirectory Then
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
        directory = Dir$()
    Loop
    Debug.Print lookinPath, j
    CountFolders = j
End Function

Sub FoldernamesToArray(lookin As String)
    Dim MyArray() As Variant

    If Not lookin Like "*\" Then lookin = lookin & "\" '<<added

    ReDim MyArray(1 To CountFolders(lookin))
    directory = Dir$(lookin & "*.*", vbDirectory)
    j = 0
    Do While Len(directory)
        If directory <> "." And directory <> ".." And _
            GetAttr(lookin & directory) And vbDirectory Then
            j = j + 1
            MyArray(j) = directory
        End If
        directory = Dir$()          'ERROR OCCURS HERE
    Loop

    Debug.Print Join(MyArray, ", ")
End Sub

Sub tester()
    FoldernamesToArray "C:\_Stuff\test\"
    FoldernamesToArray "C:\_Stuff\test"
End Sub
```